# Service Workers with Vue and Bundling

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, web-worker, commonjs, worker-loader

I use **Vue 2** with **Common.js** to generate an AMD Bundle. I need to be able to automatically register my service worker on runtime. Something that works:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-loader

The reason I need a service worker is for sending notifications. However, I am having trouble with this, as it seems that the only workers supported are in DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope or SharedWorkers. In order to dispatch "showNotification" however, I need the **Service Worker type**.

So basically what I do:

```js
import Worker from "worker-loader!./Worker.js"

const worker = new Worker()
```

Works like charm, as does this (Worker Plugin):

```js
const worker = new Worker('./worker.js', { type: 'module' });
```

However, always normal workers. Those arent service workers and I have been trying to figure this out since hours. Is there a configuration im missing to change the type? Some insight would be great.

**To illustrate what im trying to achieve:**

[image]

Registration of the Service Worker needs to happen automatically on Runtime, without me having to reference absolute or relative urls.

Any insight on how I can achieve what im trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I did not use your plugins but I used [workbox plugin for Vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-workbox-pwa). The configuration is quite simple and well documented.

*Installing in an Already Created Project*

`vue add workbox-pwa`

*Config example*

```js
// Inside vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...other vue-cli plugin options...
  pwa: {
    name: 'My App',
    themeColor: '#4DBA87',
    msTileColor: '#000000',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

    manifestOptions: {
      start_url: '/'
    },
    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' will lead to a new service worker file being created each time you rebuild your web app.
    workboxOptions: {
      swDest: 'service-worker.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly. This plugin basically takes a service worker from /src and auto registers it on runtime?

Comment: No, the plugins creates itself ```serviceWorker.js``` file in desired directory and registers it.

Comment: I installed it and added the config in vue.config but I dont see any service worker when "npm run serve". Mind showing an example in your answer?

Comment: Problem ist, that when building with common.js, I get 1 bundle which is used inside an AMD loader. I dont see the service-worker being generated and registered inside my bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `service-worker-loader` instead (which is based on `worker-loader`).

1. Install [`service-worker-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-worker-loader):

   ```sh
   npm i -D service-worker-loader
   ```
2. Create a service worker script (e.g., at `./src/sw.js`) with the following example contents:

   ```js
   import { format } from 'date-fns'

   self.addEventListener('install', () => {
     console.log('Service worker installed', format(new Date(), `'Today is a' eeee`))
   })
   ```
3. Import the service worker script in your entry file:

   ```js
   // main.js
   import registerServiceWorker from 'service-worker-loader!./sw'

   registerServiceWorker({ scope: '/' }).then(registration => {
     //...
     registration.showNotification('Notification Title', {
       body: 'Hello world!',
     })
   })
   ```

[demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vue-service-worker-notification-demo)

Comment: Hello Tony, I will try this out later and will let you know today. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Bounty expired but I will make a new one so you can have the points later :)